# Elasticsearch, inline scripts vs stored scripts

Tags: elasticsearch

The official elasticsearch guide says:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html

Store and retrieve scripts
You can store and retrieve scripts from the cluster state using the stored script APIs. **Stored scripts reduce compilation time and make searches faster.**

How do stored scripts reduce compilation time and make searches faster compared to inline scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Stored scripts are **compiled once** at the time they are stored in the cluster state, whereas inline scripts are compiled on each query invocation.

From there, it's trivial to deduce that stored scripts are faster than inline ones.